# Can you pipe a command into a running programm via batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to run a command in a running program via a batch file?

I have to address the following problem:
Currently i start a commando-based program without gui via batch file. This software takes approx. 10 seconds to start and enables to control it with command inputs. Is it possible to *pipe* a command into the program and run it after the program has started only by the batch file the program started?

Comment: This is completely unclear. You'll need to show what you want to achieve here, as you refering to sending answers to prompts? Then yes, if the application accepts stdin. i.e `echo Y|applicationname`

Comment: I guess you mean launching your "commando-based" program as a background process from your batch script and, still from the batch script, sending "commands/data" to this "commando" program ? (If yes, it's IPC, and it's possible, for example with [named pipes for PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640388/3641635)).